# Looping Through Table View Cells

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
for(NSUInteger j = 0 ; j < [sports count] ; j++){

    NSIndexPath *loopPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:j]; 

    if([pickerTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:loopPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){

        [chosenSports addObject:[pickerTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:loopPath].textLabel.text];                          

    }

}
```

This code produces a sigabrt error. The exact error is "Invalid index path for use with UITableView.  Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row.  Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible." Thanks in advance;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is correct.  [NSIndexPaths](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) consist of a row and a section number, which is especially true for table views considering how blind to your implementation they actually are (considering they rely on a datasource and a delegate).  You have a simple initializer error, try this instead:

```
for(NSUInteger j = 0 ; j < [sports count] ; j++){

    NSIndexPath *loopPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:0]; 

    if([pickerTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:loopPath].accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){

        [chosenSports addObject:[pickerTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:loopPath].textLabel.text];                          

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @CodaFi's answer you should be aware that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns `nil` for currently invisible rows.

So your loop adds only objects from the currently visible cells, which might not be what you want.

Comment: Which is why looping through cells in a table view should be done at the level of the datasource instead of the the tableview itself.